# Image property complete returns true before image is actually rendered

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to cover unloaded image containers with a fill color, until the image is completely loaded. Then I display the image and the overlay text.

But on slow connections (I use Network Link Conditioner to simulate) I get an unwanted effect. The image property "complete" returns true, and the width and height of the image is set, before the image is actually rendered on screen.

Why is this? Why is the image considered loaded even though it takes an additional 10 second before it's completely rendered?

This occur in both Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

use DOMContentloaded like

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });
```

this will be performed after your image rendered fully

Refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Comment: I see a few issues though. 
1) That would be for all images, and not per image? So if one image is really heavy, the rest would have to wait?
2) What about ajax request? I fetch new content to a feed, and would have to use the same thing there.

Comment: And this example seem to show that DomContentLoaded would not work either: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/DOMContentLoaded/Default.html

Comment: See their source code. they coded to make difference. write your script inside that function to replace src of your img tag so that it will be done after rendering completely

Comment: and do it for the image which you want to load alone. writing this function multiple time is not a problem rite?

Comment: You can't attach DOMContentLoaded to an image, only to the document.

Comment: The only way I see it, I have to attach the load event before the image src is set!